# MFP CLI 7.1 and El Capitan

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

So i upgraded to El Capitan, this version of OSX no longer ships with jdk 1.6.0 in the in the /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder, and installs new java versions in /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines

I get this error when I try to mfp status

```
/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151130-1648/server/wlp/bin/server: line 777: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is set as your JAVA_HOME environment variable? Run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in Terminal to verify. Make sure it is set to the Java version that you have installed.

You can probably set it either in `~/.bash_profile` or by using a tool such as [EnvPne](http://diaryproducts.net/EnvPane).

Comment: fixed java_home, starts now but i get this in the console when it starts     objc[39181]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Unrelated to MFP. That's a known Java defect, not fixed also in 8 yet. Harmless.